# space: ~verb해 드립니다 or verb해드립니다

Tags: grammar, verb-endings, written

How does the space work in verb + 해드립니다? Please let us know whether it should be case 1 or case 2.

Example 1.

case 1. 반송**해 드립니다** vs case 2. 반송**해드립니다**.

Example 2.

case 1. 포워드**해 드립니다** vs case 2. 포워드**해드립니다**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, both are correct.

이 경우는, '해(본용언)'와 '드리다(보조용언)'가 합쳐진 경우입니다. 맞춤법 상 본용언과 보조용언은 띄어쓰는 것이 원칙이나, 붙여 쓰는 것도 허용됩니다.

즉, **해 드립니다**가 원칙이나, **해드립니다**도 허용됩니다.